# Drools: KIE Execution Server is ruining but container is in always in stopped state

Tags: drools

I am on the way of configuring Drools Workbench and KIE Execution Server using docker pre build below docker images.

Drools Workbench Showcase
KIE Execution Server Showcase

During that course i am able to register KIE Execution Server from Drools Workbench successfully including a container that point to my build.

**However Actual problem is that registered KIE Execution Server is ruining but container is in stopped state and showing mark(!) and i am unable to start.**

Therefore please suggest if encountered same issue where server is running but container is stopped and not able to start.

Note: I didn't touched any configuration that are part of docker image.

Comment: Have you changed anything in standalone.xml? If not then you have to add some fields in <system-properties> of standalone.xml file.